# How to track a file in develop branch but not in master(or default) branch

Tags: mercurial, branch, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I have projectA execute projectB. ProjectB writes ProjectA's build info to ProjectA.buildInfo.

I have a Mercurial repo for projectB, and use HgFlow (git-flow workflow) using sourceTree. 
I would like ProjectA.buildInfo to be part of the develop branch of my mercurial repo, but not part of the default branch.

When I have removed ProjectA.buildInfo from default, develop eventually merges back into default and brings the unwanted file with it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to pay attention to the merges you do. `hg remove` the unwanted file every time you merge your development branch back into default.

In order to avoid this (easy) mistake to happen, I suggest to ward yourself against that by means of a commit hook. That hook should check whether the commit so done on default branch and fail when it detects the unwanted file(s) being added. Additionally run the same or similar as pretxnchangegroup hook on the central repository (if any).

Check `hg help config` and search for help on hooks therein. We use a hook to avoid people committing build artefacts to every branch, you could possibly extent that: https://hg.openttdcoop.org/misc/files/tip/mercurial/hooks/check_commit.py

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in a useful direction. What I think I will end up with is to pick a particular file pattern "*.buildInfo" that is assigned merge tool ":local" so that it doesn't really merge into what I want to release (that I want to keep clean), but still should keep some useful info in development branches.